# ECharts: Emphasize marker in tooltip while hovering on a line

Tags: javascript, echarts

I use Echart v5.4, and want to emphasize tooltip marker with border like https://tensorboard.dev/experiment/QFRIzZJpTZCNRzi8N7zomA/#scalars

When line chart is hovered, I want to have border around the marker.

I edited the `formatter` in `tooltip` option, but it didnt work well.

Is there any good way to make it work?

```js
option = {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    formatter: (params) => {
      let tooltip = `<p>${params[0].marker} ${params[0].seriesName}</p>`
      tooltip += `<p>${params[1].marker} ${params[1].seriesName}</p>`
      return tooltip
    }
  },
  legend: {
    data: ['Email', 'Union Ads', 'Video Ads', 'Direct', 'Search Engine']
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    boundaryGap: false,
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Email',
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'Total',
      data: [120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210]
    },
    {
      name: 'Union Ads',
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'Total',
      data: [220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310]
    },
    {
      name: 'Video Ads',
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'Total',
      data: [150, 232, 201, 154, 190, 330, 410]
    },
    {
      name: 'Direct',
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'Total',
      data: [320, 332, 301, 334, 390, 330, 320]
    },
    {
      name: 'Search Engine',
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'Total',
      data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320]
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: Can u share the options file .

Comment: added echarts code

Comment: [echart_tooltip_css](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.tooltip.extraCssText) follow this URL might be useful.